# Which of these two deck of card design pattern is more stable/ preferred?

Tags: java, oop

I am learning OOP concepts and this is in continuation of my previous question. Just for practice, I am designing a deck of cards.  I have two patterns in minds

```html
public interface ISuit {
    String getLogo();
    String getName();
}
```

```
public class Card {
    ISuit suit;
    Integer n;

    public Card(ISuit suit, Integer n) {
        this.suit = suit;
        this.n = n;
    }

    void setSuit(ISuit suit){
        this.suit = suit;
    }

    void display(){
        System.out.println(suit.getName()+","+n);
    }
}
```

Second pattern

```html
public interface Icard<T extends ISuit> {
    T getSuit();
    String getNumber();
}



public  class Queen<E extends ISuit> implements Icard<E> {
    Class<E> clazz;


    public Queen(Class<E> clazz) {
        this.clazz = clazz;
    }

    @Override
    public String getNumber() {
        return "12";
    }

    @Override
    public E getSuit() {
        try {
            return clazz.newInstance();
        } catch (InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

}
```

Obviously, the first one is more intuitive and straight-forward. Over there, I will 52 objects of cards with right suit, number as parameter. 
In the second design, I will create 13 classes for each index of cards and then instantiate them with correct suits. In future, if there is a new index, I can create a new class extending Icard.

As a newbie, I can't figure out if there are any disadvantages of the second design or if I am violating any design principle.

Could somebody please help me with this?

Comment: With the second design you'll have to create 13 nearly identical classes which is wasteful, it's much more complicated than it needs to be. Your `getSuit` method is wasteful, creating a new object with every call. Consider using an enum class for the suit. Make fields private and final, so card instances are immutable.

Comment: for learning/practicing the concepts of OOP, consider another domain like modelling an inventory of vehicles (cars, bikes, trucks), which have very different implementations and properties to each other, but share a lot of behaviour.

Answer (score 1):

52 classes (54 if you wanted to include jokers)  is *extreme*.  This is easily accomplished with one, maybe two classes, if you wanted to have another construct to represent the specific suits.

Think of it like this.  What actually makes up a card?

- The suit
- The face value
- Its proper name (i.e. 10 of Clubs)

If we want to decompose that a bit more, we could say that a suit is only ever going to be one of four values - spades, clubs, hearts, and diamonds - which lends itself well to an enumeration.

The face value varies between card games, and depending on how you want to represent Ace, it could either be the highest valued card for a suit, or the lowest valued card for the suit.  You'd want some special behavior for the face value that you want.

I see two classes to begin with - one for `Card` that defines the basic containers of all of the metadata we care about, and an enum for `Suit` that defines the four cardinal suits we support.

For joker support, you could either consider jokers to be either red or black (and you could choose an appropriate red/black suit to follow), or leave the suit undefined.  This again varies for what kind of card game you're actually playing, but it's important to consider.

Comment: could you add why the Suit interface wouldn't be appropriate in this particular example?

Comment: I glossed over the interface since it doesn't make sense to implement an interface that's only ever going to be used by one type of object ever.  I could add that into the answer, but I feel the omission of it indicates its importance/relevance/significance.

Comment: @Makoto my reasoning behind making it a interface was that in future I want to be able to add new suits if needed. I guess that can be done thru enum.

Comment: @Dude there are no more suits though. Using cards may be the wrong domain to practice this to the extend you seem to want (e.g. finding a usecase for generics).